# Can anyone help to identify this fruit?

Tags: species-identification, fruit

[image: This plant looks more like a shrub - not a tree]

It stays the same color when ripe. It's about the same size as a pear. Grows in sub tropical climate of Meghalaya, India.

[image]

Comment: It seems like cutting it open and showing the inside would give us more insights

Comment: Will cut it open and check if it is indeed Solanum Muricatum as suggested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this looks a lot like a pale variety of [Solanum Muricatum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_muricatum) or Pepino dulce/melon/pear.

[image]
[image]

It's native to South America, but I think that it would be able to be cultivated in India as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. This very much looks like the plant I have as well.

Comment: @JamesSyngai Did you know already that you can mark an answer as _accepted_, if it answers your question? You just need to click the check mark symbol next to the up and down arrows of that answer.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like Tinda (*Praecitrullus fistulosus*), also known as round melon, Indian round gourd, Indian baby pumpkin, apple gourd, or Indian squash.

[image]

Source: https://www.bigbasket.com/pd/10000372/fresho-tinda-250-gm/

[image]

Source:  http://fruitspecies.blogspot.com/2008/10/tinda-indian-round-gourd.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not fully sure but in my opinion the leaves look more like chili pepper leaves and it resembles a tomato or eggplant in the fruit, with a similar stem. It's likely a member in the nightshade family (also known as Solanaceae) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae .

For reference, a green eggplant:

[image: A green Eggplant]

However, I am unsure what the specific species might be as the leaves don't match the typical eggplant pattern.